# Make text bold via an onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make the text bold by clicking a button. See below code, the problem I'm having is that I'm unable to pass the textarea ID to the `boldTF()` function.

```
<button type="button" id="tfButton">Add text</button>
<div id="InputsWrapper"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tfCont = 0;
    var InputsWrapper = $("#InputsWrapper");
    var x = InputsWrapper.length; 
    var namefield = $("#tfButton");

    $(namefield).click(function() {
        tfCont++;
        $(InputsWrapper).append('<div>' + '<div class="name" id="InputsWrapper_0' + tfCont + '">' + '<input type="textarea" id="field_' + tfCont + '" class="fTypex" placeholder="Type Here"/>' + '<br /><button type="button" onclick="boldTF("field_' + tfCont + '")">Bold</button>' + '<br>' + '</div>' + '</div>');
        x++;
        return false;
    });

    function boldTF(tmp){
        document.getElementById(tmp).style.fontWeight = "bold";
        //alert(tmp);
    };
});
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your HTML code?

Comment: Don't write inline event handlers for your button. Simply attach a delegated event handler to some element (here it looks like `#InputsWrapper` would be appropriate) and let that one automatically take care of everything.

Comment: `onclick="boldTF("field_' + tfCont + '")"` will break parsing because of the double quotes inside double quotes. Use unobtrusive handlers instead, as Jon says.

Comment: @xDaevax: I've edited my post by including the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inline event handler and use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
    $(this).closest('div.name').find('input').css('font-weight', 'bold')
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jj7kturz/)**

Answer (score 1):

Many issues

1. `<input type="textarea"` should be `<input type="text"` or `<textarea ...></textarea>`
2. Use the class to get at the field
3. No need to mix DOM access with jQuery
4. jQuery can attach event handlers on dynamically created objects using delegation.

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/k2yux990/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#tfButton").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        var tfCont = InputsWrapper.length;
        $("#InputsWrapper").append(
            '<div class="name" id="InputsWrapper_0' + tfCont + '">' +
            '<input type="text" id="field_' + tfCont + '" class="fTypex" placeholder="Your first name"/>' +
            '<br /><button type="button" class="boldTF">Bold</button><br /></div>');
    });
    $("#InputsWrapper").on("click", ".boldTF", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().find(".fTypex").css({"font-weight":"bold"});
    });
});
```